# How to add inline comments while creating a pull request in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

While creating pull requests in bitbucket I want to add inline comments under "diff".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that while creating the pull request. Once you've submitted the PR, though, then you can add as many inline comments as you want.